# List<String> subset of another List<String> ignoring case?

Tags: java

Imagine I have the following lists

List `a` - `("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")`

List `b` - `("oNe", "two", "THREE")`

I want to consider `b` as a subset of `a` (ignoring the case).

For now I'm using loops and a bit of lambda like so

```
boolean subset = true;                    
for(String bWord : b) {
   if(!a.stream().anyMatch(aWord -> aWord.equalsIgnoreCase(bWord))) {
     subset = false;
     break;          
   }
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do this maybe with lambdas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transform `a` to a `HashSet` of lower case `String`s, which would make it faster to check for subset (since it would take constant time to check whether any element of `b` belongs to `aset`, instead of the linear time required for checking for inclusion in a `List`):

```
Set<String> aset = a.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
boolean subset = b.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).allMatch(aset::contains);
```

P.S., you are using the term **subset**, but in fact what you are checking for is not whether one `List` is a **subset** of the other, since your `List`s are not `Set`s, which means they may contain duplicate values. It would make more sense to begin with `Set`s in the first place.

EDIT:

If using `containsAll` seems better to you, at least run it on two `Set`s instead of two `List`s. You'll get linear running time instead of quadratic running time:

```
Set<String> aset = a.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
Set<String> bset = b.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
boolean subset = aset.containsAll(bset);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I agree with what you said but I had to accept the another answer because I'm not at liberty to change data type to `Set` at this time.

Comment: @prettyvoid My answer can be used even if you don't change the type of the original `a` and `b` from `List` to `Set`, and it's still more efficient than calling `contains` or `containsAll` for a `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the info again. I did some benchmarks between the various methods mentioned by you and Maroun and it looks like containsAll on lowercase lists is the fastest. Could you elaborate why? Please see this https://pastebin.com/dfPQs83Z

Comment: @prettyvoid You tested on tiny Lists (2 and 3 elements), where the different between O(N) and O(N^2) is negligible. You'll see that the Set solution performs better than the List solution for large Lists/Sets.

Comment: I decided to accept this answer (even though I went with what Maroun suggested for now) because it's much more efficient on large lists and future visitors here will probably have big lists to deal with.

Answer (score 7):

Convert arrays to lowercase:

```
a.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and use [`containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
b.containsAll(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Subclass of TreeSet with an case-insensitive Comparator

```
public class MyStringSet extends TreeSet<String> {

    private static class CaseInsensiteStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase());
        }

    }

    public MyStringSet() {
        super(new CaseInsensiteStringComparator());
    }

    public MyStringSet(Collection<? extends String> arg0) {
        super(new CaseInsensiteStringComparator());
        addAll(arg0);
    }

    public MyStringSet(Comparator<? super String> arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }

    public MyStringSet(SortedSet<String> arg0) {
        super(new CaseInsensiteStringComparator());
        addAll(arg0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> b = Arrays.asList("eins", "drei", "zwei");
        MyStringSet a = new MyStringSet(Arrays.asList("Vier", "DRei", "zWei", "einS"));

        System.out.println(a.containsAll(b));

    }

}
```